# ExtJS Component References

Tags: extjs

I have a controller file in my ExtJS application that I use to communicate information between various views. I've realized that in many of my functions, I use a lot of `Ext.getCmp('someComponent')` and had a bad code smell.

If I continually reference some component, what would be the best way of storing a reference and then referring to it whenever I'd like without creating the extra boilerplate code?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: I am currently using 4.0

Comment: Have a look here http://extjs.eu/blessing-and-curse-of-refs/